# Find a reasonable h

Tags: high-frequency, machine-learning

> The mid-price at time $t$ is denoted by $$p_t = \frac{s_t^{a,1} +
>  s_t^{b,1}}{2}.$$
>
> This mid-price can evolve in minimum increments of half a tick but is
>   almost always observed to move at increments of a tick over time
>   intervals of a millisecond or less. In our feature set, each limit
>   order book update is recorded as an observation. Each observation is
>   labelled bases on whether the mid-price will increase, decrease or
>   remain over a horizon $h$: $$Y_t = \Delta p^t_{t+h},$$ where $\Delta
>  p^t_{t+h}$ is the forecast the discrete mid-price changes from time
>   $t$ to $t+h$, given measurement of the predictors up to time $t$. The
>   forecasting horizon $h$ can be chosen to represent a fixed number of
>   events or can be a fixed time interval.

This definition is from *A High Frequency Trade Execution Model for Supervised Learning* (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03870.pdf).

According to that definition, what would be a reasonable $h$ here?

Comment: The parameters for a machine learning algo are often found by trial and error. That being said I would start with something small like 1 and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several things:

1. Data: if your data has prices updated every hour, any h < 1 hour just doesn't make sense
2. Goal: in practice, if your looking to build a strategy, you'll be limited by your infrastructure. I.e. if you're using a retail broker, predicting for h = 10 milliseconds won't help you, since you can't update your quotes that frequently
3. Noise: generally, the shorted the horizon, the less noise you'll have in your observations, but something ~ 1min should be good enough.